# Reload module on modification

Tags: python, python-import

Is there idiomatic way to reload python modules on edit? I am keeping configuration in `my_config_module.py` file and want to automatically detect and load config changes. Currently I am trying something like this but I find it ugly and unsafe:

```
import my_config_module
import importlib

last_modification = os.stat('my_config_module.py').st_mtime

while True:
    last_mod = os.stat('my_config_module.py').st_mtime
    if last_mod != last_modification:
        importlib.raload(my_config_module)
        last_modification = last_mod 
    # main loop, some of my code
```

Comment: You could take a look at how [%autoreload is implemented for IPython](https://github.com/ipython/ipython/blob/master/IPython/extensions/autoreload.py).

Comment: The [`watchdog`](https://github.com/gorakhargosh/watchdog) module might be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

You should keep data in a separate file and reload it when it's modified (and thus, avoiding the need of reloading code).

Comment: this is what I wanted to avoid, don't want to parse anything from json or xml

Comment: This should be a comment not an "answer".

Comment: @gst They still have a point, though. Configuration should usually be kept in a format that lends itself well to storing configuration data, not in code. (Also: safety). If OP doesn't like JSON, they can use YAML or TOML or similar that has a friendlier structure.

Python modules are not meant to be reloaded on a regular basis.

Comment: @blubberdiblub I was not questioning the validity of the raised point and I did not downvote the answer, just voiced my *opinion* by posting a comment.